# How to Restart Windows Update Service in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-update, services

I'm running into an issue with Windows Update on Windows 7 Professional. I am totally up to date in Windows Updates as of last week, but discovered this issue [today] during my Sunday morning PC maintenance ritual. In CONTROL PANEL -> SYSTEM & SECURITY -> Windows Update, when I select "Check for Updates", I get a pop-up stating:

"Windows Update cannot currently check for updates, because the service is not running. You may need to restart your computer."

I've re-started several times, checked that the service hadn't been disabled at start up, and I've googled extensively on the topic - but have come up with nothing. I know there must be some way to start the service from the cmd line, and I would like to know how to get the service to start at boot.

Please let me know if I have left any details out that may aid in formulating a response. Any of the community's excellent insights would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can try stopping and restarting Windows Update Service (wuauserv). Open a command line window (run as administrator) and enter the following lines:

```
net stop wuauserv  
regsvr32 %windir%\system32\wups2.dll  
net start wuauserv
```

If that does not help, try Microsoft's Fix It service to reset your Windows Update Components: [How do I reset Windows Update components?](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971058/en-us)

Comment: I recommend using the Microsoft utility. It will sort out almost any windows update related issue on any windows platform.

Answer (score 4):

I found [this webpage](http://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-7/cannot-run-windows-update-on-a-windows-7-pc/) and that fixed it in two minutes.

> The first thing to do is to stop the Windows Update service on your Windows 7 machine. You can do this by going to Start and typing in services.msc in the search box.
>
> Next, press Enter and the Windows Services dialog will appear. Now scroll down until you see the Windows Update service, right-click on it and choose Stop.
>
> Now that the Windows Update service has been disabled, you need to go to the following folder and delete all the files and folders inside of it:
>
> C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\
>
> Once you have deleted everything, go back to the Services dialog and right-click on the Windows Update service and choose Start. All the files and folders will be re-created and hopefully you can start downloading updates for your PC.

Comment: steps worked on windows 7 machine.

Answer (score 1):

I sent my laptop into HP to get fixed and it was re-imaged or set to factory new when it came back to me. I bought it in 2012, now its 2013 and thus the computer was still thinking it was in 2012 after starting up for the first time. I changed time and date to the current 2013 date and then tried to get updates and this time it worked.